# Creating gems with app assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler to make a gem with bundler and this is great for gems where i only need a lib, is there a standard practice for gems where i need to create mini apps with assets/controllers/models/views ?

Answer (score 7):

You would be looking to create an engine at that point. Reading the [Engines Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) guide should give you a great start on that.

The bare-bones components you need inside your gem are a file at `lib/your_gem.rb` that serves the purpose of simply requiring whatever it is your gem needs. If your gem has no other dependencies, then it looks like this:

```
require 'your_gem/engine'
```

One line, so much power. The `lib/your_gem/engine.rb` file it requires has this code in it:

```
module YourGem
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

By simply inheriting from `Rails::Engine`, this triggers an inheritance hook on `Rails::Engine` that notifies the framework that there is an engine at the location of your gem.

If you then create a file at `app/assets/stylesheets/your_gem/beauty.css`, you can then include that in your application (assuming you have the asset pipeline enabled, of course) using this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "your_gem/beauty" %>
```

Now that I've given you the short version of it, I really, really, really recommend reading the [Engines Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) top to bottom to better understand it.